# Getting Java Class Names from a Java File

Tags: java

I need information about where each java class is located. There can be multiple classes in a java file. Therefore, getting java file name is not correct way... One possible way that I can come up with is using Eclipse AST library. But I'm wondering that there is an easier way because I'm not familiar with Eclipse AST... If I should use Eclipse AST, please give me some code snippet that help me search for related information.

**Update:**

Input: a location of java project

Output: mapping information between java file and java classes declared in the java file.

e.g.

In A.java,

```
public class A {
    System.out.println("A class");
    class InnerA{
        System.out.println("A inner class");
    }
}

class B {
    System.out.println("B class");
}
```

A.java file links to A.class, A$InnerA.class and B.class

Comment: If you had class `A` and `B` defined in `/foo/bar/A.java`, what would you consider the correct answer for the location of `B`? Are you requiring filename plus line number?

Comment: Are you talking about java (source) files or class (binary) files?

Comment: I think you mean "Eclipse JDT" and not "Eclipse AST".

Comment: Sorry for insufficient question. I need mapping information between java source(or class) files and classes. For example, "A.java(class)" file contain A and B class.

Comment: @Duncan is right. I mean Abstract Syntax Tree.

Comment: @Jung-Hyun Do you need to discover available classes or do you already have a list that you just need filenames for?

Comment: @Duncan I am aware that he wants to use the AST from Eclipse which is located in the "Eclipse JDT" package. AST is not a library but a concept.

Comment: @Duncan I have classes and source files. But I don't know what java file each class belongs to...

Comment: Ah.. I see. In fact, I'm not familiar with Eclipse JDT...

Comment: @Jung-Hyun Please be more specific. When your application runs, what are its inputs? Do you point it at a folder and it needs to find `.java` files and print out the classes contained within?

Comment: @Duncan Okay. I will update the question.

Comment: Having multiple top level classes is really a rare thing. I don't think I've ever seen it in practice and it should be avoided. You have to support this as well?

Comment: @Puce Ahh.. That's why I can't find related information in the Web. I hope that there is no such case. But I don't want to miss that possibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume you know how to find all the `.java` files within your project directory. Using [javaparser](http://code.google.com/p/javaparser/) you can list the types declared in each file as follows:

```
public class ParserTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    CompilationUnit cu;

    try (FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("C:\\tmp\\Test.java")) {
      cu = JavaParser.parse(in);
    }

    List<TypeDeclaration> types = cu.getTypes();
    ArrayList<String> parents = new ArrayList<>();

    for (TypeDeclaration typeDeclaration : types) {
      printTypes(typeDeclaration, parents);
    }
  }

  private static void printTypes(BodyDeclaration item, List<String> parents) {
    if (item instanceof TypeDeclaration) {

      TypeDeclaration type = (TypeDeclaration) item;

      System.out.println(getClassName(type.getName(), parents));
      List<BodyDeclaration> members = type.getMembers();

      List<String> cloneOfParents = new ArrayList<>(parents);
      cloneOfParents.add(type.getName());

      for (BodyDeclaration bodyDeclaration : members) {
        printTypes(bodyDeclaration, cloneOfParents);
      }
    }
  }

  private static String getClassName(String name, List<String> parents) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (String string : parents) {
      builder.append(string);
      builder.append(".");
    }

    return builder.append(name).toString();
  }
}
```

In my example, `Test.java` contained:

```
public class Test {

  class InnerClass {
  }

}

class Foo {}
```

and the code printed:

```
Test
Test.InnerClass
Foo
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't noticed @Duncan's answer.. I used JDT AST parser. I read this post,
http://www.programcreek.com/2011/11/use-jdt-astparser-to-parse-java-file/, and I could write code as follows.

```
//use ASTParse to parse string
public static void parse(String str) {
    ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS3);
    parser.setSource(str.toCharArray());
    parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);

    final CompilationUnit cu = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);
    cu.accept(new ASTVisitor() {
        String packageName="";

        public boolean visit(TypeDeclaration node) {
            String className=node.getName().getFullyQualifiedName();
            if (packageName!="")
                System.out.println(packageName+"."+className);
            else
                System.out.println(className);

            return false;
        }

        public boolean visit(PackageDeclaration node) {
            packageName=node.getName().getFullyQualifiedName();
            return false;
        }
    });

}
```

It's not what I exactly want because this code doesn't print inner classes. However, By searching classes in the class directory, I could get inner classes whose names start with the class names that are printed.

Thank you, @Duncan. I read your code and ran the code. It works like charm. I notice some grammars in your code are Java 7 grammars. I'm not familiar with it yet. But I learn it from your code. :)